# Minimum cost of a rectangle storage container

Tags: calculus

A rectangular storage container with an open top is to have a volume of $70$ cubic meters. The length of its base is twice the width. Material for the base costs $70$ dollars per square meter. Material for the sides costs $5$ dollars per square meter. Find the cost of materials for the cheapest such container. 
I know that $$v=LWH$$
$$L=2W$$
$$C(cost)=70LW+5(2LH+2WH)=70LW+10LH+10WH$$
$$V=(2W)WH=2HW^2$$
$$2HW^2=70$$
$$C=70(2W)W+10(2W)H+10(WH)=140W^2+30WH$$
$$H=70/2W^2=35/W^2$$
$$C=140W^2+30WH=140W^2+30W(35/w^2)=140W^2+1050W/W^2$$
$$C=140W^2+1050/W$$
So now I would need to find the minimum of the function, but this is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Hi Natalie, if you are planning to ask many more questions on math.se, would you please try to learn a little bit of LaTeX?  It makes it so much easier to read and you will find that more people are prepared to answer your questions.  I have made a start to show you the main thing you need to do.

Comment: Okay, can you give me some links so I can? I'm sorry if I caused any problems!

Comment: For a start just look and see what I have done.  (Hint: I have only added one symbol - but lots of times.)  For future reference you might like to bookmark [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Answer (score 1):

$C(w) = 140w^2 + \dfrac{1050}{w}$, then $C'(w) = 280w - \dfrac{1050}{w^2} = 0 \to w = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1050}{280}}$. This $w$ gives the lowest cost. You can find the rest using this $w$.

Answer (score 0):

take the derivative of that final answer you have then find its zeros, once you have found the zeros choose the smallest number larger than 0 and plug it in to your original equation, that will give you the smallest cost.